# MongoDB: How to query document where the currentDate is newer than endDate (expired)

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB: How to query document where the currentDate is newer than endDate (expired). These fields are in the same document.

```
"startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-27T11:00:00.000Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2020-03-05T10:59:00.000Z")
```

Comment: Use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator - it allows comparing fields within the same document.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RhsjmlzM5Ok)

```
db.collection.find({
  endDate: {
    "$lt": new Date()
  }
})
```